# Vigor 130: Do PPPoE and offer WAN IP via DHCP on LAN

Tags: router, pppoe

Is it possible to configure the Vigor 130 or Vigor 165 to act as PPPoE Client and offer the received WAN IP to the LAN side via DHCP e.g. to a Router.

Maybe there is s feature name or wording for that, but I am not aware of any.

I do not want to have a double NAT solution.

Comment: You are looking for [bridge mode](https://www.voicehost.co.uk/help/bridged-mode-routers)

Comment: No, I'm not. Thats my current setup. I really want it with DHCP.